# PHP query works in localhost but breaks on live server

Tags: mysql

As the title suggests, I have a query that works fine in localhost but on my live environment I get a 500 server error. My PHP version locally is 7.4 but the live server uses 7.3.

The error I get is

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 
1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL 
server version for the right syntax to use near '(partition by prop_slug order by 
  prop_client) as rn 
  FROM listing_details 
  JOI' at line 4 in /hermes/bosnaweb23a/b60/ipg.site/site/index.php:23 
Stack trace: 
#0 /hermes/bosnaweb23a/b60/ipg.site/site/index.php(23): PDOStatement->execute() 
#1 {m
```

My query looks like the below, but as I said this works fine in the local environment.

```
 $get_listings = $db->prepare('SELECT *
 FROM (
 SELECT *,
  row_number() over(partition by prop_slug order by prop_client) as rn
 FROM listing_details
 JOIN prop_gallery
 ON prop_gallery.prop_gallery_id = listing_details.prop_slug 
 WHERE prop_slug LIKE prop_gallery_id OR prop_gallery_id LIKE prop_slug
 AND listing_details.prop_mandate = 1
 ) x
 where rn = 1');
 $get_listings->execute();
 $listings = $get_listings->fetchAll();

 if (!$listings) { 
  echo 'Error: No Listings.';
 }
```

Comment: What are your MySQL versions?

Comment: compare database user access privilege with local database. Seem like not user which you using in live server not able to create partition.

Comment: Theyre both 5.6.32 @AbraCadaver

Comment: Thanks @aviboy2006, they both have all privileges selected however

Comment: That's funny because _window functions_ like `over()` and `row_number()` were introduced in 8.0.

Comment: Try running same query directly on MySQL console or if you are using MySQL workbench do it there.

Comment: Errors are from MySQL, and have nothing to do with PHP.

Comment: agree with @AbiusX check your MySQL part as i also suggested.